# Running Gradle ShadowJar Plugin only on specific subproject

Tags: groovy, gradle, dropwizard, gradle-plugin

**Please note:** Even though my `myapp-server` is a [DropWizard app](http://dropwizard.io/manual/core.html), this is strictly a **Gradle** question; I only mention DropWizard for good measure.

I have a multi-project build that I am building with Gradle:

```
myapp/
    myapp-client/
    myapp-shared/
    myapp-server/
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

Where `settings.gradle` looks like:

```
include ':myapp-shared'
include ':myapp-client'
include ':myapp-server'
```

I have successfully got Gradle to compile my Groovy source code, run unit tests, generate GroovyDocs, and package both binary and source JARs for all 3 subprojects. The build invocation for which is: `gradle clean build groovydoc sourcesJar -Pversion=<whatever version I specify>`.

The `myapp-server` is actually a project that I need to run the [Shadow JAR plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) on, which is *usually* executed via `gradle clean build shadowJar`.

Here is my `myapp-server/build.gradle`:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.ServiceFileTransformer

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'shadow'

mainClassName = 'com.me.myapp.server.MyAppServer'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:0.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':myapp-shared')
    compile (
        'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:0.7.1'
    )
}

shadow {
    outputFile new File(destinationDir, "${outputJarBaseName}.${extension}")
    transformer(ServiceFileTransformer)
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}

run {
    args 'server', 'config.json'
    if (System.getProperty('debug', 'false') == 'true') {
        jvmArgs '-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005'
    }
}

artifacts {
    shadowJar
}
```

My question: **How do I configure Gradle to only run the `shadowJar` task on my `myapp-server` subproject, and not on any of the others?** Ideally, I could just have my build invocation be something like:

```
gradle clean build groovyDoc sourceJar shadowJar -Pversion=<blah>
```

And then somehow configure Gradle to ignore running `shadowJar` on everything *except* `myapp-server`. Ideas?

---

**Update**

When I run `gradle clean build groovyDoc sourceJar shadowJar -Pversion=0.1.3` I see a bunch of Gradle output that ends with:

```
:myapp-shared:groovydoc
:myapp-client:sourcesJar
:myapp-server:sourcesJar
:myapp-shared:sourcesJar
:myapp-server:copySignedLibs UP-TO-DATE
:myapp-server:shadowJar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 16.315 secs
```

However when I drill down into `myapp-server/build/libs/myapp-server-0.1.3.jar` and open it (extracting it like a ZIP), I only see my compiled classes inside of it, not all the classes from all of its dependent JARs (it should be a "Fat JAR"). For instance, `myapp-server` depends on DropWizard. All the DropWizard classes should be inside this JAR. All of DropWizard's transitive dependencies should have class files inside this JAR, etc.

Comment: As far as I understood `shadow` is added to `myapp-server`? What's the result of running `gradle clean build groovyDoc sourceJar shadowJar -Pversion=<blah>` from root?

Comment: Thanks @Opal (I'd upvote you if I had the rep to do so), please see my update which answers your question. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is that project located online? May I have a try?

Comment: No @Opal this is just local to my machine.

Comment: That's a pity. Could You provide an example on github for instance?

Comment: Yes @Opal however it will take me until tonight, I'll send an update once its up there, thanks for the help so far!

Comment: No worries. I may wait. Just let me know when it's ready.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait here @Opal, please see the [GitHub repo I added](https://github.com/herpylderp/myapp). If you clone it, and then run `gradle clean build shadowJar -Pversion=1.2.3` from the parent `myapp` directory, you will see that `myapp-client-1.2.3.jar` and `myapp-shared-1.2.3.jar` build correctly. **However**, `myapp-server-1.2.3.jar` is **not** a fat JAR, hence Shadow Jar seems to skip/ignore it for some reason. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked out the project located [here](https://github.com/herpylderp/myapp).

After fetching the sources I've run: `gradle clean shadowJar` in `myapp` directory. As far as I see, there is a jar file created under `myapp/myapp-server/build/distributions` that seesm to be the *fat* jar You're looking for (also when file size is taken into consideration). After entering the mentioned distributions directory and running `java -jar myapp-server.jar` the server is started. It seems that it's all working fine. Am I right?

Also running `curl -v -X GET http://localhost:8080/myapp/dosomething` gives the following output:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /myapp/dosomething HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 05 Jan 2015 14:59:50 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) - how did you know to look in the `build/distributions` directory? That doesn't seem to be documented anywhere in the Shadow Jar plugin GitHub doc...

Comment: This is the location where distribution artifact is being built. I've also run `gradle clean shadowJar` and investigated all the jars created. It seems that You can change the location as well as the name under which artifact is built. If it's clear and works, please accept.

Comment: Thanks again @Opal (+1) - I'm not trying to be difficult here, just trying to learn so that I don't have to ask these types of questions in the future. When you say "this is the location where distribution artifact is being built", is this a Gradle convention that Shadow Jar simply piggybacks off of? Or is this something that *should* have been obvious to me if I had read the Shadow Jar docs? I guess the root of the problem was that I was just looking in the wrong place for the fat JAR. I'm trying to understand *why* I was looking in the wrong place, and its either because:

Comment: (a) Shadow Jar is leveraging a Gradle convention that I didn't know about (in which case I need to read the Gradle docs more), or (b) Shaodw Jar uses its own convention to put the fat JARs under `build/distributions`. If that's the case, then is this documented somewhere on their site?

Comment: I think that it's just a matter of experience. Gradle `application` plugin is built on top of `distribution` plugin. I've used that plugin so I remembered about *distributions* folder. When it comes to `shadow` plugin I read in docs that it can be integrated with application plugin - that how I found the place to start searching. And I found desired arifact at once. Trust me, there's no magic here. With time You'll get more experienced and will know how it may work. I can tell You that the gradle scripts you prepared look really well.

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking to only reference one sub project to shadowJar you could do it as follows.

```
gradle clean build groovyDoc sourceJar :myapp-server:shadowJar -Pversion=<1.0>
```

You can drill down to your subprojects tasks via `:<project name>:<task name>`

Reference:
https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html
57.4. Running tasks by their absolute path